# NSDateFormatter error converting date from string

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have a date in NSString format with this content: 29/02/2012 12:00:00 AM

I'm trying to convert it to NSDate object in order to make comparisons using:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
```

But when I use dateFromString: method I'm getting a null value.

What I'm missing?

Thanks.

-EDIT-

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    NSLog(@"INFO -> Test Date: %@",[df dateFromString:testQuestions.endDate]);
    NSLog(@"INFO -> Test Date String: %@",testQuestions.endDate);

    if ([[df dateFromString:testQuestions.endDate] earlierDate:[NSDate date]])
    {
        currentTestIsBeingSolved = NO;
    }
```

Log:

```
2012-04-09 22:15:29.073 Otsuka On[27184:707] INFO -> Test Date: (null)
2012-04-09 22:15:31.816 Otsuka On[27184:707] INFO -> Test Date String: 29/02/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

EDIT--

As @trudyscousin suggested I've started a new project and added this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

    NSLog(@"INFO -> Test Date: %@",[df dateFromString:@"29/02/2012 12:00:00 AM"]);
...
```

Now I'm not getting null but the date is not the same:

```
2012-04-09 22:26:19.189 TestDate[54705:207] INFO -> Test Date: 2012-02-28 23:00:00 +0000
```

What is going on with the dates?

Any config in Xcode?

Thanks.

Comment: The date when printed directly seems off because it's being displayed in GMT (note the time zone `+0000` at the end of the string). See any of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+nsdate+off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you've suffixed your date and time with "AM" is what is doing it. You have to provide for that as well:

```
@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I used the format as you suggested but I'm still getting null.

Comment: @NemeSys : I ran your code with the added format specifier and successfully got a date:     `NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *foo = [df dateFromString:@"29/02/2012 12:00:00 AM"];
    NSLog(@"%@", foo);`

Comment: I've checked everything twice and still not working for me. I can't understand because your code is correct, I don't know why is not working for me.

Comment: I've edited the question with the block of code that I'm using.

Comment: @NemeSys : Fire up a new project and put those four lines into the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, quick and dirty. Look for the output in your log. See if it works there.

Comment: @NemeSys : The only thing I can think of is to make sure your date string is not nil, and is in the format the date formatter (as you've set it up) is expecting.

Comment: I've edited the question. In new project I'm passing a hardcoded date same in the previous project. In the old project I'm still getting null in new project a wrong date.

Comment: If you look at the date, you'll see it's referenced against GMT. The date is correct, but not necessarily for your locale. Now if you set up a time zone for the date formatter...